# Set header of a specific page only

Tags: header

How can I set the header of only one specific page in the LaTeX document? `\markboth` does not seem to fit, as I have the document class report & it would affect more than one page somehow. Setting `\rhead{}` new would change the header completely for the pages after that one specific page too..

Comment: define a new heading style then: `\thispagestyle{specialheading}`

Comment: how would the special heading look like?

Comment: it's your requirement, you haven't said what page style you want. you mention `\rhead` so presumably you are using fancyhdr style? which provides those commands to define to define page styles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A thorough review of the `fancyhdr` documentation would be helpful to you.  It will only take a few minutes, and will pay huge dividends in your future LateX endeavors.

Your particular task here is simple; the `\thispagestyle` command exists for precisely this purpose.  So define a pagestyle and use `\thispagestyle` to apply it to a particular page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
    \fancyhead{Special Header}\fancyfoot{}
}%
\fancyhead{Normal Header}
\fancyfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\thispagestyle{mystyle}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

`\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{*header stuff*}` is what defines your pagestyle; here, "Special Header".  We then use the normal `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` commands to define our normal fancy header (or whatever variants you may prefer).  When we reach the page we want to have the special header, we use `\fancypagestyle{mystyle}` (with "mystyle" replaced with whatever name you may have given it).  This will produce the following:

[image: Results]

Hope that helps.